# Android: Split the string into multiple lines based on comma

Tags: android, split

Its a calculator app & i'm trying to do is summarize the calculation in the vertical row in preview activity pane with each set of 8 values.

```
String [] parts = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",.......]
```

The length of the string can be more or less than the above given data.

What I want is to split the above String Parts containing the first 8 characters with separater "comma" in a separate string.
ex:-

```
String [] part1 =  ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
String [] part2 =  ["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"]
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you mean split the array or the string? Because your example is an array of strings.